# What is the default cisco "enable password" username

Tags: cisco

I have a question to the cisco IOS specialists. My teacher asked me a question: what is the default username for "enable password/secret". He told me that it may be found in the internet, but i need to ask google unconditionaly. I've been thinking about the question without success.

Does anybody know, what is the username for enable mode in cisco?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cisco routers have different categories for authentication. A category for command line access (called EXEC). A category for PPP access. After all we wouldn't want a ISP's clients to be granted EXEC access just because they successfully authenticated their PPP session. The authentication to enter enable mode is simply one more category; a little unusual in that there is no user-supplied username.

Some authentication backends -- like RADIUS -- always need a username field. If we use those authentication backends to authenticate the enable mode category (using a configuration like `aaa authentication enable default group EXEC-RADIUS`) then the router supplies the backend with `$enab15$` in the RADIUS `User-Name` field.

Note that this isn't the same as saying there is a default username for enable mode.

(The above answer assumes `aaa new-model`, which is fair as it's hardly new anymore.)

Answer (score 2):

There's no username for enable mode.

From exec mode, you enter the command "enable" and the device ask for the password.

You may also (depending on the IOS version and the actual configuration) type "login" and provide the username and password of a account configured on the switch (either locally or through radius or tacacs) that, upon successful login, will be put directly in privileged mode

Comment: The username begins from $ and ends with $. How does it sound? And it can be found on cisco website.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that, in IOS, their no username. As a example, on [this page](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/configfun/configuration/guide/ffun_c/fcf005.html#wp1000960) in the note you will find the following sentence: *When the "enable" password is used as the HTTP server login authentication method, any username entered will be ignored; the server will only verify the "enable" password.*  Are you sure this is about IOS and not another Cisco OS like NX-OS?

Answer (score 0):

I was corrected. Iogin via the console cable to ios has no enable password.

I posted the below. I thought some older IOS's used cisco but I can't find evidence of that. To many diffrent devices to keep straight I guess. These below are logins, not direct to ios.

Username:Cisco

Password:Cisco

Or

Username:cisco

Password:cisco

and some

Username:blank

Password:Cisco or cisco

Comment: Those are default login accounts, not enable passwords.

Comment: You know.... Your right.